# Cohomology of a local system and Deligne's weight filtration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a stratified variety, and let $i:S\hookrightarrow X$ be the inclusion of a stratum.  Let $F := H^k(i^!\operatorname{IC}_X)$.  This is a local system on $S$ whose fiber at a point is isomorphic to the degree $k$ compactly supported cohomology of the stalk of $\operatorname{IC}_X$ at that point.

Now let’s assume that $S \cong \mathbb{C}^\times$, and let $V$ be the fiber of $F$ at $1\in S$.
Let $\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}(V)$ be the monodromy map.  Then the cohomology of $S$ with coefficients in $F$ is equal to the cohomology of the complex
$$H^0(\mathbb{C}^\times) \otimes V\overset{1-f}{\longrightarrow} H^1(\mathbb{C}^\times) \otimes V.$$

Question:  Does the map $1-f$ have to be strictly compatible with the weight filtrations on these groups?

We know that $H^0(\mathbb{C}^\times)$ has weight 0 and $H^1(\mathbb{C}^\times)$ has weight 2.  This would mean that $1-f$ can only be nonzero if $\operatorname{gr}(V)$ contains two different summands whose weights differ by exactly 2.  In particular, if $V$ is pure of some weight, then $1-f$ would have to vanish.  This is the conclusion that I want, but I am suspicious; it sounds too strong!

Comment: In what sense is that a "local system"?  Did you mean to write "constructible sheaf"?

Comment: It is a constructible sheaf that is locally constant (because $S$ is a stratum).

Comment: I see now.  I thought you were looking at the extension over $X$ of a sheaf on $S$.

Comment: You are right to be suspicious. If one takes the direct image of the constant sheaf under $z \mapsto z^2$ one gets a local system which splits into two pieces, both of which are pure, and one of which has no cohomology. The non-trivial summand gives a counter-example to your hopes. Making $1 - f$ compatible with weight filtrations is a tricky business, in the mixed Hodge world it is given by the limit mixed Hodge structure...

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson: I agree that $f \neq 1$ in your example, but how is this a counterexample to my hopes?  Is there a way to obtain the sheaf that you describe via my construction?

Comment: @use54343: What do you mean by "your construction"? Restricting $IC$ to a strata? Doesn't taking $\mathcal{L}$ to the the local system I describe (an $IC$) recover what you want. (It is not clear to me how your second paragraph relates to the first. It seems your question is simply a question about variations of mixed Hodge structures on $\mathbb{C}^*$ and their cohomology. It would be much clearer if stated in this way.)

Comment: In the question, $\operatorname{IC}_X$ is supposed to denote the perverse extension of the constant sheaf from the open stratum of $X$.  Sorry if this was unclear!  (ps - user54343 is me.  For some reason I was unable to login as myself yesterday.)

Comment: The question could be rephrased as follows:  Assume that the cohomology groups of the stalks of $\operatorname{IC}_X$ are all pure.  Is it possible to obtain a nontrivial local system on $S$ via the construction in the first paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the variety with equation $y^2=tx^2$. Let $S$ be the locus with $x=0,y=0,t\neq 0$. Then clearly the sheaf at each point of $S$ is a sum of one-dimensional vector spaces from the surfaces $y=\pm \sqrt{t}x$. Monodromy swaps these two, so the action is nontrivial.

What you can get from purity in this case is that the unipotent monodromy is nontrivial. The operator $f-1$ does not behave in a predictable way on weights because it is not Galois-equivariant. But because the monodromy must be quadi-unipotent, we can take a power $f^n$ which is unipotent. Then $N=\log f^n/n$ is a well-defined map $V \to V$ that subtracts $2$ from the weight, showing that the unipotent part is trivial by exactly the argument you give.